# What is a Shockley-Read current?

Tags: electric-current, semiconductor-physics

What is a [Shockley-Read current](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=current&as_epq=shockley+read)? Googling it brings up nothing. Is it possible this is some obscure name for a type of diode current? I know what the Shockley-Read-Hall process is, is it related to that?

Comment: I would interpret it as being the recombination current. But that is a guess - my standard device physics books don't use 'Shockley-Read current'.

Comment: @JonCuster It doesn't seem to be a term that's in use any more, if it ever was, and I can't find any references to it at all. However wikipedia does have a table comparing diffusion and drift current so perhaps it's those two. Recombination current of course makes sense given the SRH process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shockley-Read current is the current in a pn-junction (or bipolar transistor) that is due to the electron-hole recombination or generation in the depletion zone according to the *Shockley-Read-Hall* mechanism involving the capture/emission of charge carriers on deep levels in the energy band gap. It is particularly important in the semiconductor silicon where its is the dominant current in pn-junctions as opposed to the so-called diffusion current of the original Shockley diode model.

Historically, this recombination/generation mechanism has been described by [W. Shockley and W.T. Read in a Physical Review article published in 1952](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.87.835). The same mechanism has been proposed independently by R.N. Hall in Physical Review articles in 1951 and [1952](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.87.387).

Comment: I found the 1952 papers and added links.  Both refer to the 1951 paper, but the citation to the 1951 paper seems to contain a half-century-old typo.

Comment: @rob - Thank you for these helpful links. I was also looking for the 1951 Hall paper but I could not find the cited page 228 in Phys. Rev **83**.